# display image and text when google map marker is clicked in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have made google map v2 demo. I have number of latitudes and longitudes to be displayed on map as markers, I have done this successfully.

But, now I want to display images to them when marker is clicked, that is also almost done but my problem is for all the markers I am getting single image.

**code**

```
package com.amar.travelonwards;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.amar.travelonwards.utility.ImageLoader;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Multi_Map_Marker extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    int[] img = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.aro, R.drawable.back };
    CameraPosition cameraPosition;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    int i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.multi_map_marker);

        try {
            // Loading map

            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(Multi_Map_Marker.this);
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     * */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initilizeMap() throws IOException {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map_multi)).getMap();

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            // create marker
            for (int i = 0; i < HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.latitude_list
                    .size(); i++) {

                String latitude = HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.latitude_list
                        .get(i);
                String longitude = HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.longitude_list
                        .get(i);
                String name = HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.hotel_name_list
                        .get(i);
                String hotel_images = "http://images.travelnow.com"
                        + HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.hotel_image_list.get(i);
                System.out.println("MYIMAGES  " + hotel_images);
                URL url = new URL(hotel_images);
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                        .getInputStream());
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latitude), Double
                                        .valueOf(longitude))).title(name)
                        .snippet("Bed " + Integer.toString(i))
                /* .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image)) */;

                try {
                    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                    cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latitude), Double
                                    .valueOf(longitude))).zoom(12).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

            }

            try {



                googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        View myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
                        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                                .findViewById(R.id.title));
                        ImageView image_view = ((ImageView) myContentsView
                                .findViewById(R.id.image_view));
                        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());

                        for (i = 0; i < HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.latitude_list
                                .size(); i++) {


                            try
                            {
                                i = Integer.parseInt(marker.getSnippet());
                            }
                            catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
                            {
                                i = 0;
                            }
                            String hotel_images = HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.hotel_image_list
                                    .get(i);
                            System.out.println("MYIMAGES  " + hotel_images);
                            imageLoader.DisplayImage(hotel_images, image_view);


                        }
                        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                                .findViewById(R.id.snippet));

                        return myContentsView;
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            // adding marker

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            initilizeMap();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way.  When you add the marker to the map grab the id that is assigned to it.

```
marker = mMap.add(markerOptions);
```

now save the marker id

```
x.markerId = marker.getId();
```

You can't extend markeroptions because it is final so make a class that has a markerOptions and id.

```
Class  X {
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
string markerId;
string pathToImage;
int  imageId;
string myCustomMarkerProperty;
}
```

save x into a collection

```
blah...
```

when the marker is clicked use it's id to lookup in the collection.

```
 marker.getId()
```

Comment: I'm just typing this in without a code editor but this is another way to keep track of markers.

Answer (score 0):

Method `getInfoContents(Marker marker)` will give you clicked marker as parameter.

Instead of looping through all items in your `mNewsFeeder` lists and loading every single image in image view, you should find item (index) in list that corresponds to given marker and load its image.

Since you are not setting `snippet` value when you are creating marker, probably the simplest way to achieve that would be to set index while creating markers and then use that index to get proper image.

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
      new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latitude), Double.valueOf(longitude)))
      .title(name)
      .snippet(Integer.toString(i));
```

Instead of loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.latitude_list.size(); i++) {
```

use

```
try
{
    i = Integer.parseInt(marker.getsnippet());
}
catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e)
{
    i = 0;
}
final String hotel_images = HotelListActivity.mNewsFeeder.hotel_image_list.get(i);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(hotel_images, image_view);
```

Comment: Please see my edit,I have edited as per yours but now when i click on marker,App hang "not responding". :(

Comment: First you have to remove loop in `getInfoContents` method, and then you haven't used my exact code for adding snippet but `.snippet("Bed " + Integer.toString(i))`, and that will prevent you to parse integer value from snippet. Also you should leave original code as part of your question.